# Linear regression dependence on end points?

Tags: regression

When playing a bit with a live linear regression visualization at
http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m28709
I noticed that point at the ends of the X range have a large influence on the slope of the regression line.

Is there an accepted way to give weights depending on the X coordinate to reduce the influence of possible outliers at the border of the X range?
Or maybe another method?

Comment: There's loess, splines, robust regression...probably other methods too.

Answer (score 3):

There are algorithms for fitting lines to data that are robust to extreme x-values (points which would be high leverage in ordinary regression) and there are algorithms which explicitly seek to bound either the leverage or influence.

One simple robust method in the simple regression case is Theil regression; the effect of a single large x-outlier is limited . There are other robust methods, and some have better breakdown point than Theil regression (though its breakdown point is almost 30%). Beware, though - not all forms of 'robust regression' are robust to high leverage points.

An example of a bounded-leverage version of least-squares type regression is discussed [here](http://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/proceedings/papers/1992_080.pdf):

Akkerboom, J.C. and N.J. Nieuwenbroek (1993). *Representative Bounded-Leverage Regression Estimation for Finite Populations*, 1992 Proceedings of the ASA.